# Why is the classify function not giving the desired output?

Tags: machine-learning

[image]

Greetings,

I have created 4 sample data and classified them to 4 classes as shown. However, when I want to test the ClassifierFunction, the output is not as expected. I have realized that for some reason, it neglects the inner two data sets. When tested with only 2 data sets, it works just fine. Why, when I give create a sample data to test, which is almost exactly as the training data, does it give me a different output than expected? For example in the image, the output should give me "Compound 3", but gives me "Compound 4" instead. The image explains everything.

I appreciate your help,
Thank you

```
data1 = Table[Sin[x] + 10 + RandomReal[{0.5, -0.5}], {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}];
data2 = Table[Sin[x] + 50 + RandomReal[{0.5, -0.5}], {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}];
data3 = Table[Sin[x] + 100 + RandomReal[{0.5, -0.5}], {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}];
data4 = Table[Sin[x] + 150 + RandomReal[{0.5, -0.5}], {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}];

trainingset = {data1 -> "Compound 1", data2 -> "Compound 2", data3 -> "Compound 3", data4 -> "Compound 4"};
c = Classify[trainingset]

data = Table[Sin[x] + 100 + RandomReal[{0.5, -0.5}], {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}];
c[data]
```

Comment: Please, post copyable code not images. And format it properly -- more on that in the help centre.

Answer (score 2):

I assume what you want to do is classify individual values (such as for instance *12.232*) into one of four classes and that your `data1` to `data4` are training examples for each individual class. In this case the syntax for `Classify` is slightly different and this is how you need to specify the training data:

```
Classify[<|class1->{example11,example12,}, class2->{example21, example22}|>]
```

You can convert your training data via `trainingset // Map@Reverse // Association` and accordingly train your classifier

```
c2 = Classify[trainingset // Map@Reverse // Association]
```

and use it to classify values

```
c2[12.232] (*yields Compound 1*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike @Sascha, I assume that you are trying to do exactly what your code says: namely, classify data into four classes using one example of a length 63 feature vector for each.

This is challenging for some types of classifier, in particular the default (`Method->"LogisticRegression"`), which (I believe) seeks to separate the classes using a linear combination of features.

Changing to a different `Method` e.g.

```
c = Classify[trainingset, Method -> "NearestNeighbors"]
```

will give an answer that I think you will find more reasonable, but the real solution is to provide more examples for each class in the training set.

Answer (score 1):

This is, perhaps, an extended comment. Mathematica comes with a lot of built-in classifiers (e.g. language, face detection etc). I think it is unreasonable to expect presenting any data form to classify. Mathematica is certainly'smart' in trying to match input with classifier. However, data pre-processing happens whether we realize it or not. This extracts features/predictors that can be used for the particular model chosen. I suggest *caveat emptor*. This is not a criticism of Mathematica (or MatLab or Python or whatever tools you use) but an expression of the need to look at, understand and perhaps pre-process  data (as well as understanding [to some degree] what the algorithms are doing...I am NO EXPERT).

The following is completely artificial and in fact I use `data` as a test object just because the plots in OP are "so distinct" prompting the concernregarding `Classify`

Using the information from OP:

```
td = {data1, data2, data3, data4};
lab = {"Compound 1", "Compound 2", "Compound 3", "Compound 4"};
mean = Thread[Mean /@ td -> lab];
var = Thread[Variance /@ td -> lab];
median = Thread[Median /@ td -> lab];
ct = {"LogisticRegression", "SupportVectorMachine", 
   "NearestNeighbors"};
tup = Tuples[{{mean, var, median}, ct}];
cfs = Classify[#1, Method -> #2] & @@@ tup;
```

Three *features* are extracted (mean, variance, median of data) and three classifiers.

Some classifier measurements to illustrate (how somewhat obviouslysome measure of central tendency discriminates).The `data` variable is used in a contrived manner.

```
func[prop_] := 
 Grid[Partition[
   MapThread[
    Column[{Framed@Row[#2], 
       ClassifierMeasurements[#1, Thread[data -> lab[[3]]], prop]}, 
      Alignment -> Center] &, {cfs, 
     Tuples[{{"Mean: ", "Variance: ", "Median: "}, ct}]}], 3], 
  Frame -> All]
```

e.g.

```
func["Accuracy"]
func["ConfusionMatrixPlot"]
```

[image]

There are a lot of new features in Mma 11. I hope we our human learning goes *pari passu* with the machine learning tools so we can have value as well as fun. (end of philosophical rant)